# Can C# application be installed on Garmin Navigation Device?

Tags: c#, navigation, device, garmin

I want to run my own application built in C# using .Net compact framework 3.5 on `Garmin Navigation` device. Is it possible?

Can I also communicate with the Garmin software from my own C# application?

## Updated

Is there any other company that offer navigation devices in which we can install or run c# application?

Comment: Firstly, Garmin make a lot of devices. You would need to be very specific about what device, as they will all have different capabilities. I would expect "runs arbitrary code" is a minority feature (if at all), though - and "supports CF" is even less likely. Communicating is more likely - there's an API for that IIRC

Answer (score 3):

Note that Garmin device's software running on [Linux](http://developer.garmin.com/open-source-software/linux/).
As Marc Gravell noted it could be possible technically to run CLI on it.

You also can communicate with their services via [API](http://developer.garmin.com/web-products/web-services/):

Comment: Re your "on linux" - that might be a *good* thing... if you can run mono (cli on linux) on a Raspberry Pi (and you can), then the garmin devices might be *technically* able to do it. However, there's a big difference between "able" and "willing".

Comment: I just updated my requirement. Is there any navigation device that supports .Net compact framework 3.5?

Comment: that type of question isn't valid on SO http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139399/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question

Comment: @Liam: There could be some one who has already done this type of task. Therefore, I asked about any other device. In my opinion, this type of question is valid.